# Solutions to ax = by mod m?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given congruence  $ax = by \bmod m $ for known integers $a,b,m$, with  $m $ composite, can this relation be simplified or solved?

Comment: By dividing $m$ by $\gcd(a,b)$ (which is a necessary condition to have solutions) you can assume WLOG that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and solve the equation $ax-by=km$ for every $k$ this will give you an infinte number of solutions $(x,y)=(mku+k'b, mkv+k'a)$ <here $u,v$ are the integers verifying $ua-vb=1$ (To summarize the solution follows the same idea as Linear Diophantine equation)

Comment: You should be able to find the complete solution in any elementary number theory textbook. I recommend leaving the answer as congruence classes (modulo some divisor of $m$), rather than writing it in terms of $k$ as Elaqqad suggested.

Comment: @GregMartin There isn't a complete solution anywhere, either in a book or online